# insert email into sqlite field, in awk script

Tags: bash, sqlite, awk, formatting

I am inserting **email** into **SQlite** table field, in `awk` using:

```
system("sqlite3 database.db " sprintf("\"UPDATE tbl SET email = '<a href=\\\"mailto:%s\\\">%s</a>' WHERE field = '%s'\", m[1], m[1], l))"))
```

After that when using `SELECT` query from bash:

```
function do_query() {

    sqlite3 -batch database.db <<- "end_of_message"
        #...
        #...
        #.. outputs to "o.html"

        select field1,email,field3 from tbl; # <-- HERE IS THE SELECT
            QUERY FOR THAT EMAIL FIELD
    end_of_message
    #...
    #... here just embedding output of this into my template file
    #... which is some simple HTML

    sed -e '
    /\${template_tag}/ {
        r o.html <--output from sqlite3 select statement
        d
    }
    ' template.html > out.html

}
```

,rendering this in browser I am getting this **literally**:

```
<a href="mailto:worldnamegroup@gmail.com">worldnamegroup@gmail.com</a>
```

,instead of `worldnamegroup@gmail.com` as a `clickto` mail link.

So in my `source view` in browser I see this:

```
&lt;a href=&quot;mailto:worldnamegroup@gmail.com&quot;&gt;worldnamegroup@gmail.com&lt;/a&gt;
```

`<` and `>` are being converted into `&lt;` and `&gt;` respectively.

How to insert that `email` so that I have in my browser properly rendered email
link?

**edit 1**
It's also strange I get other output ok from that select, like `<td>` for
example. But that's done internally by **sqlite** when `.mode` set to `html`.

**edit 2**
I found that the real problem may be in sqlite mode option. When set `.mode
column`, it shows all well in terminal, but when `.mode html`, it shows:

```
<TD>&lt;a href=&quot;mailto:worldnamegroup@gmail.com&quot;&gt;worldnamegroup@gmail.com&lt;/a&gt;</TD>
```

**edit 3**
Until someone comes up with something smarter, I made a workaround like this:

```
cat o.html |recode html..ascii
```

,then used the output of that, to feed my `template`.

Comment: Show the code that embeds the output into the template file.

Comment: @CL. See edits I made.

Comment: IMHO you shouldn't use these backslashes in `href=\\\"mailto:%s\\\"`, because you show this inclosed into a strong-quoting structure (single quotes) that should be enough to protect the double quotes from being interpreted before the string is sent to the `system` command. So try removing your 2x3 backslashes...

Comment: @jaybee Those were added later, because without them, `"` did not show around `href` attribute, and the result was the same. So it did solve that issue. Anyway it can't influence those `<a>` tags as they are outside of triple `\\`.

Comment: @CL. It has nothing to do with rendering, because when I open that `o.html` file in VIM, I see those `&lt;`, so the problem arises before.

Comment: Why do you have an extra `a>` in `</a>a>`?

Comment: @jaybee Where? :) It was copy-paste issue. In my code it's ok.

Comment: Ok, maybe a way out of this: you can write your `mailto` link with single quotes as well as with double quotes, so I would suggest `SET email = '<a href=\\'mailto:%s\\'>%s</a>' WHERE`. This is also reducing the number or backslashes from 3 to 2, so that the string sent to **sqlite** contains `UPDATE tbl SET email = '<a href=\'mailto:AA\'>BB`.

Comment: @jaybee See edits I made.